# Problema para cambiar el tamaño de texto en un JOptionPane

Tags: java, html, java-swing

Os comento mi problema:

Estoy intentando cambiar el tamaño de los mensajes que muestro en un *JOptionPane* y se que el texto puedo ponerlo como un mensaje normal por ejemplo `"Hola"` o que también puedo ponerlo en formato HTML puesto que también funciona por ejemplo `<HTML><h1>Hola</h1></HTML>` y así este se modifica y se cambia a un tamaño equivalente a `<h1>`.

Pues bien lo que estoy intentando hacer es mostrar un *arrayList* con el siguiente formato `Nombre --> puntos` en un *JOptionPane* pero se ve muy pequeño con lo cual lo que he pensado es en meter eso dentro de un código HTML para que me lo muestre mas grande, algo así: `<HTML><h2>Nombre --> puntos</h2></HTML>` para que así sea mas grande pero no me funciona correctamente. Os muestro el código referente a eso:

```
public String getRankingToString() { //Mete en un String el contenido del array list.
    String mensaje = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ranking.size(); i++) {
        mensaje += ranking.get(i).getNombre() + " -->" + 
                ranking.get(i).getPuntuacion() + "  goles" + "\n";
    }
    return mensaje;
}

public String mostrarRanking() { //Este metodo devuelve un String con el contenido
  //del arraylist en forma de String que obtiene del metodo anterior
  //y le añade al principio y al final la parte de html para usar en el JOptionPane 

    String rankingString = "<HTML><h2>"; //Inicializo el codigo HTML
    String end = "</h2></HTML>"; //Final del HTML que "pego" luego al final del String
    if (ranking.isEmpty()) {
        rankingString = rankingString + "RANKING VACIO" + end;
        return rankingString;
    } else {

        rankingString = rankingString + getRankingToString() + end;
        return rankingString; //Devuelve el contenido del arraylist en forma de String
    }
}
```

Lo que pasa es que a la hora de mostrarlo en el *JOptionPane* o no lo lee correctamente o solo lo aplica a 1 elemento.

Código del JOptionPane:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, partido.mostrarRanking(),
        "RANKING", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Y este es el resultado:

1. Cuando el ranking esta vacío: (caso if(ranking.isEmpty()):

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Cuando se añade a 1 persona:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Cuando en el ranking hay mas de 1 persona:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis la primera línea si que me respeta el código HTML pero luego ya lo ignora por completo y deja de funcionar.

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacer para que funcione?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Utiliza `<BR>` en lugar de `\n`, he comprobado que luego de los saltos de linea el formato de HTML deja de funcionar.

Comment: Siiii era esoo, muchas graciass :)

Answer (score 0):

Este código es un poco más útil para mí.

Puedes controlar el tamaño de cada opción cambiando el h2 por h1,h3.. hasta h6.

```
Object seleccion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "<html><h2>Opcion 1</h2><h2>Opcion 2</h2><h2>Opcion 3</h2><h2>Opcion 4</h2</html>",
            "Selecciona una opcion", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, // null para icono defecto
            new Object[] { "<html><h2>1</h2></html>", "<html><h2>2</h2></html>", "<html><h2>3</h2></html>", "<html><h2>4</h2></html>" }, null);

    System.out.println(seleccion);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Comand Promt, aunque este código puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, la respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones con solo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de lo que hace y por qué o cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).